# How to obtain a list given this database

Tags: prolog

I am learning prolog and currently stuck on this exercise. I am trying to obtain a list of Ontario teams that outputs:

From the database below.

```
city(ottawa,ontario).
city(guelph,ontario).
city(kingston,ontario).
city(gatineau,quebec).
city(montreal,quebec). 
team(ravens,ottawa).
team(ggs,ottawa).
team(gryphons,guelph).
team(queens,kingston).
team(torrents,gatineau).
team(stingers,montreal).
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
setof(X, city(X,ontario), L). %This returns L = [guelph,kingston,ottawa]
```

How would I go about the next step to obtain

```
L = [ggs, gryphons, queens, ravens].
```

Answer (score 0):

source

```
city(ottawa,ontario).
city(guelph,ontario).
city(kingston,ontario).
city(gatineau,quebec).
city(montreal,quebec). 

team(ravens,ottawa).
team(ggs,ottawa).
team(gryphons,guelph).
team(queens,kingston).
team(torrents,gatineau).
team(stingers,montreal).

city_team(_city_,_team_) :-
city(_city_,_province_) ,
team(_team_,_city_) .
```

demo

```
?- setof(_team_,city_team(_,_team_),_teams_) , T = _teams_  .
T = [torrents] ? ;
T = [gryphons] ? ;
T = [queens] ? ;
T = [stingers] ? ;
T = [ggs,ravens]
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISO Prolog standard specifies three meta-predicates that collect solutions for a goal: `bagof/3`, `setof/3`, and `findall/3` (there's also a de facto standard `findall/4` meta-predicate). These meta-predicates have different semantics, notably on how they deal with variables on the goal argument (the second argument) that are not in the template argument (the first argument). All of them are described as meta-predicates as they take a goal as one of the arguments. Let's illustrate their semantics using your `city/2` predicate.

First, we try `bagof/3`:

```
| ?- bagof(City, city(City, State), Solutions).

Solutions = [ottawa,guelph,kingston]
State = ontario ? ;

Solutions = [gatineau,montreal]
State = quebec

yes
```

Notice that the solutions are *aggregated* by state, which is a variable that occurs in the goal but not in the template. Let's try it now with `setof/3`:

```
| ?- setof(City, city(City, State), Solutions).

Solutions = [guelph,kingston,ottawa]
State = ontario ? ;

Solutions = [gatineau,montreal]
State = quebec

yes
```

Notice the difference in the first solution? They are *ordered*. The `setof/3` predicate sorts solutions in standard order (using term comparison) and also eliminates duplicates.

The meta-predicate `findall/3`, however, doesn't aggregate solutions for the bindings of variables in the goal not occurring in the template:

```
| ?- findall(City, city(City, State), Solutions).

Solutions = [ottawa,guelph,kingston,gatineau,montreal]

yes
```

Therefore, you can use it to answer your question. The following query returns all teams:

```
| ?- findall(Team, team(Team, City), Teams).

Teams = [ravens,ggs,gryphons,queens,torrents,stingers]

yes
```

To get only the teams in the state of Ontario we can use:

```
| ?- findall(Team, (team(Team, City), city(City,ontario)), Teams).

Teams = [ravens,ggs,gryphons,queens]

yes
```

We can also get the list ordered by using `setof/3`:

```
| ?- setof(Team, City^(team(Team, City), city(City,ontario)), Teams).

Teams = [ggs,gryphons,queens,ravens]

yes
```

The `City^` construct instructs `setof/3` (can also be used with `bagof/3`) to not aggregate solutions by bindings for the `City` variable.

More can be written about these predicates, notably about *variable terminology* and the `^/2` operator but this answer is getting long. One final remark, however: In general, for clarity and best performance, avoid using complex goal arguments with these meta-predicates. Is often clear to define an auxiliary predicate. For example:

```
state_team(State, Team) :-
    team(Team, City),
    city(City, State).
```

Using this predicate:

```
| ?- setof(Team, state_team(ontario,Team), Teams).

Teams = [ggs,gryphons,queens,ravens]

yes
```